# ASP.NET and WEBSERVICES

Tags: asp.net, web-services

Is it possible to remotely access the database over internet using ASP.NET and .mdf file. If yes then How?

I'm searching for the solution from last 4 days and came up with the idea of Webservices. I learned XML for this but the problem is I dont know how to use the webservices. I mean how to embed it in my project so that the database could be accessed remotely?

Please help and thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need to do a little more background work yourself here.  It's possibly one of the most common scenarios for ASP.NET developers.  There's any number of awesome resources online to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "embed it in my project". The web service is web application that needs to be hosted on a web server, so you cannot embed it in your project as your project will be accessing it remotely (i.e. from another location). You can add it as another project to your solution, and then **consume** it in your project. You can google and learn how to consume a webservice.